# react-native reload js programmatically on android native

Tags: android, react-native, reload

Is there a way to reload the javascript programmatically on android as in the menu?

[React-native android menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a7sy.png)

I would like to do so directly in Native  Java

Comment: So i found the solution by checking in the code directly.
In the class who extends from ReactActivity call this : getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager()
.getDevSupportManager().handleReloadJS();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i found the solution by checking in the code directly.

In the class who extends from ReactActivity call this :

```
getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager()
.getDevSupportManager().handleReloadJS();
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me work out a very hacky temporary solution to a difficult bug in my app!! :)